# Storing data that's related to a user but that's it

Tags: neo4j

In our graph database, I'm looking to store misc data that a user does but isn't really related to anything such as changing a password or updating a username. (there are about 20 other use cases that we have)

I attached two possibilities below but I don't know which one is better if I'm looking to eventually do queries such as how many peopled the password yesterday or who changed the password yesterday.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several more options and as always it depends. What are your queries and what is your most likely entrypoint into the graph ? For example :

[image]

Those are just three possibilities and the model really depends on how you want to query your data. What else could I have done ?

1. I could have done away with the Event nodes all together and put the properties on a relationship between User and EventType. Hard to use that relationship as an entry point into the graph though.
2. I could have added a Date node which could be an entry point into the graph (or maybe an index on eventDate is sufficient).
3. I could have ...

There is no single right (or wrong) answer. The better choice is often the one that reflects your reality/business the best.

Hope this helps.

Regards,
Tom